# Python open file and delete a line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need a program that imports a file.

My file is:

```
1 abc
2 def
3 ghi
4 jkl
5 mno
6 pqr
7 stu.
```

I want to delete lines 1, 6 and 7.

I have tried the following to import the file:

```
f = open("myfile.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open("myfile.txt", "w")

if line = 1:
    f.write(line)
f.close
```

Comment: Sorry SO is not a code writing service, could you show your efforts and any errors

Comment: You DONT import a file to read it, you OPEN it. Change the title.

Comment: To answer, you read line by line, erase the file and write only the lines you want (or write them to a new file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could remove those lines as follows:

```
lines = []

with open('myfile.txt') as file:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(file, start=1):
        if line_number not in [1, 6, 7]:
            lines.append(line)

with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(lines)
```

By using Python's `with` command, it ensures that the file is correctly closed afterwards. This approach could also be converted to a list comprehension as follows:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as file:
    lines = [line for line_number, line in enumerate(file, start=1) if line_number not in [1, 6, 7]]

with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(lines)
```

The Python [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) function is used to return an index for each item that is returned. By starting this from `1` it can be used to provide a line number for the file that is being read.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Open your file and read the lines into a list called input
input = open('my_file.txt', 'r').readlines()

#create a list of lines you want to skip
lines_to_skip = [1, 6, 7]

with open('my_new_file.txt', 'w') as output:
    for i, line in enumerate(input):
        # check to see if the line number is in the list.  We add 1 because python counts from zero.
        if i+1 not in lines_to_skip:
            output.write(line)
```